# How can i solve dns confusion problem in my domain?

Tags: dns, nameservers

I have a dns confusion problem in my domain, there are more than 2 months that I changed the nameservers of my domain to cloud housting vps but sometimes I find that the domain displays the page of my previous host namecheap as shown in the picture how can I always force the domain to give the google server and not the namecheap server?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hlu4T.png)

Comment: This is not for StackOverflow but for ServerFault. And please, use punctuation, capitals and line feeds to make you're question readable.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, I check the status of my domain propagation using this tool:

[whatsmydns.net](https://www.whatsmydns.net/#NS/lbrry.com)

Checking yours, I see that all servers are pointing to the right NS, as well as the A records are always responding with the same two IP addresses from cloudflare, which seems correct.  I would recommend doing a full cache clear on the device you are testing and try again.